# How to add xsi type value namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very new to XSLT, can you please let me know XSLT code to be used to convert below input to below output XML?

This is my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tutorials.xsl"?>
<n:Envelope xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <n:Header>
  </n:Header>
   <n:Body xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <ns1:sayHello xmlns:ns1="http://webservice_product/helloworld">
         <toWhom>Micky</toWhom>
         <toMe>123</toMe>
         <objAs>
            <id>323232</id>
         </objAs>
      </ns1:sayHello>
   </n:Body>
</n:Envelope>
```

This is my desired output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tutorials.xsl"?>
<n:Envelope xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <n:Header>
  </n:Header>
   <n:Body xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <ns1:sayHello xmlns:ns1="http://webservice_product/helloworld" xsi:type="ns698:Product" xmlns:ns698="urn:objects.prodcuts.com">
         <toWhom>Micky</toWhom>
         <toMe>123</toMe>
         <objAs>
            <id>323232</id>
         </objAs>
      </ns1:sayHello>
   </n:Body>
</n:Envelope>
```

I tried hard to achieve desired output XML, it didn't help me. Moreover Stack Overflow is not allowing me to paste all my XSL code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired XML output is not namespace well-formed as the `xsi:type` attribute used the prefix `xsi` without any declaration for it. Assuming you want to add that declaration on the `ns1:sayHello` element you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns1="http://webservice_product/helloworld"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:sayHello">
  <ns1:sayHello xsi:type="ns698:Product" xmlns:ns698="urn:objects.prodcuts.com">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </ns1:sayHello>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply that stylesheet with Saxon 6.5.5 to the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tutorials.xsl"?>
<n:Envelope xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <n:Header>
  </n:Header>
   <n:Body xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <ns1:sayHello xmlns:ns1="http://webservice_product/helloworld">
         <toWhom>Micky</toWhom>
         <toMe>123</toMe>
         <objAs>
            <id>323232</id>
         </objAs>
      </ns1:sayHello>
   </n:Body>
</n:Envelope>
```

I get the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tutorials.xsl"?><n:Envelope xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <n:Header>
  </n:Header>
   <n:Body xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <ns1:sayHello xmlns:ns1="http://webservice_product/helloworld" xmlns:ns698="urn:objects.prodcuts.com" xmlns:xsi="h
ttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns698:Product">
         <toWhom>Micky</toWhom>
         <toMe>123</toMe>
         <objAs>
            <id>323232</id>
         </objAs>
      </ns1:sayHello>
   </n:Body>
</n:Envelope>
```

Comment: You really saved me a day, when i say day it means 24 hrs. Thank you so much.

Comment: Would you point me to the tutorial which says about @* | node() and other identity patterns?

Comment: Also how can i add schema based validation to the xsl so it always generates compliant xml?

Comment: Any match pattern of the form `match="foo | bar"` is just an abbreviation of having two templates `match="foo"` and `match="bar"` with the same content. With `match="@* | node()"` you match attribute nodes with `@*` and other nodes (with the exception of document nodes) with `node()`. The identity transformation template does a shallow copy of the matched node and processes any attribute and any child nodes with `apply-templates select="@* | node()"`. That allows you to add templates for the nodes you want to transform.